# Distinct Sets in Z3

Tags: z3

I have the following program:

```
;;; Sets
(declare-fun lock_0 (Int) Bool)
(declare-fun lock_1 (Int) Bool)
(declare-fun lock_2 (Int) Bool)
(declare-fun lock_3 (Int) Bool)

;;; verify if sets lock_0 and lock_1 haven't elements in common
(assert (exists ((x Int)) (=> (lock_0 x) (not (lock_1 x)))))

;;; verify if sets lock_2 and lock_3 haven't elements in common
(assert (exists ((x Int)) (=> (lock_2 x) (not (lock_3 x)))))

;;; Sets only contain 1 for Lock_0 and lock_1 or 2 for lock_2 or lock_3
(assert (forall ((x Int)) (= (lock_0 x) (= x 2))))
(assert (forall ((x Int)) (= (lock_1 x) (= x 2))))
(assert (forall ((x Int)) (= (lock_2 x)  (= x 1))))
(assert (forall ((x Int)) (= (lock_3 x)  (= x 1))))

;;; set [l1]
(declare-fun SL1 (Int) Bool) 
;;; set only contain 1
(assert (forall ((x Int)) (= (SL1 x) (= x 1))))
;;; SL1 subset lock_2
(assert (forall ((x Int)) (=> (SL1 x) (lock_2 x))))

;; sat
(check-sat)
( get-value (( lock_0 1 )))
( get-value (( lock_0 2 )))
( get-value (( lock_1 1 )))
( get-value (( lock_1 2 )))
( get-value (( lock_2 1 )))
( get-value (( lock_2 2 )))
( get-value (( lock_3 1 )))
( get-value (( lock_3 2 )))
( get-value (( SL1 1 )))
( get-value (( SL1 2 )))
```

Result:

```
sat
((( lock_0 1 ) false))
((( lock_0 2 ) true))
((( lock_1 1 ) false))
((( lock_1 2 ) true))
((( lock_2 1 ) true))
((( lock_2 2 ) false))
((( lock_3 1 ) true))
((( lock_3 2 ) false))
((( SL1 1 ) true))
((( SL1 2 ) false))
```

I need to generate `lock_0` and `lock_1` the following sets:

```
[] - Empty set
[2]
```

And to generate `lock_2` and `lock_3` the following sets:

```
[] - Empty set
[1]
```

But the sets `lock_0` and `lock_1` can not have elements in common.

But in the end I get:

```
( get-value (( lock_0 2 ))) true
( get-value (( lock_1 2 ))) true
```

the result is true for everyone and should be false in one case, for example:

```
( get-value (( lock_0 2 ))) false
( get-value (( lock_1 2 ))) true
```

For the sets can not contain equal elements.

Same problem to `lock_2` and `lock_3`.

If I add:

```
;;; Set [l2]
(declare-fun SL2 (Int) Bool)

;;; set only contain 2
(assert (forall ((x Int)) (= (SL2 x) (= x 2))))
;;; SL2 is subset lock_0
(assert (forall ((x Int)) (=> (SL2 x) (lock_0 x))))

;; unsat
(check-sat)
```

I hope that the result is unsat, but as the sets (`lock_0 and lock_1` or `lock_2 and lock_3`) are equal I'll get sat.

For example:
If I obtain `lock_0 = []` and `lock_1 = [2]` and `lock_2 = [1]` and `lock_3 = []`, the program was correct.

How can I solve this problem?

**START EDIT**

To adding this piece of code:
`(assert (forall ((x Int)) (or (not (lock_0 x)) (not (lock_1 x)))))`

the result is unsat. And it should be sat.

So how can I generate for the same set, the empty set or the set {2}? Or it is not possible to do?

If this is not possible, then we can make the element 0 is the empty set? But for that I can only have the following sets:

```
[0] - empty set 
[2]
```

So I do: `(assert (forall ((x Int)) (= (lock_1 x) (or (= x 0) (= x 2)))))`

But if I want the sets `lock_0` and `lock_1` may also have 3 as an element should get:

```
[0] - empty set
[2]
[3]
[2,3] - may not include zero, since only the zero should be used as the singleton set [0]
```

So I do: `(assert (forall ((x Int)) (= (lock_1 x) (or (= x 0) (and (!= x 0) (or (= x 2) (= x 3)))))))`

Is that right?

Another question: if I want to create a function that takes a set as I do that? For a set is a function.
For example:

```
(define-fun example ((s1 Set) (s2 Set) (x Int)) Int
  (if (and (s1 x) (not (s2 x)))
      (* x x)
      0))
```

But I do not know what to get instead of Set (Set s1), can help me please.

**END EDIT**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see some problems in your encoding.

First, the command

```
;;; verify if sets lock_0 and lock_1 haven't elements in common
(assert (exists ((x Int)) (=> (lock_0 x) (not (lock_1 x)))))
```

is asserting that there is an element `x` such that `x` is not in `lock_0` or `x` is not in `lock_1`. This assertion is almost vacuous. It is just preventing both "sets" from simultaneously containing all integers. Your comments suggests that you are actually trying to assert

```
(assert (forall ((x Int)) (or (not (lock_0 x)) (not (lock_1 x)))))
```

That is, the intersection of both sets is empty.

Second, you say you expect/need `lock_0` and `lock_2` to be the empty set, but you asserted

```
(assert (forall ((x Int)) (= (lock_0 x) (= x 2))))
(assert (forall ((x Int)) (= (lock_2 x)  (= x 1))))
```

These two assertions are essentially saying that `lock_0` is the singleton set `{2}`, and `lock_2` is the singleton set `{1}`.

BTW, if we replace

`(assert (exists ((x Int)) (=> (lock_0 x) (not (lock_1 x)))))`

with

`(assert (forall ((x Int)) (or (not (lock_0 x)) (not (lock_1 x)))))`, (1)

the problem becomes trivially unsatisfiable after we assert

`(assert (forall ((x Int)) (= (lock_0 x) (= x 2))))`  (2)

`(assert (forall ((x Int)) (= (lock_1 x) (= x 2))))`  (3)

Since, (1) is saying that `lock_0` and `lock_1` do not have elements in common, and (2) and (3) are saying they are the singleton set `{2}`.

**EDIT** (for extra questions)

If we want to say that `lock_0` is the empty set, we can just say that it is always false

```
(assert (forall ((x Int)) (not (lock_0 x))))
```

The command

```
(assert (forall ((x Int)) (= (lock_1 x) (or (= x 0) (= x 2)))))
```

is asserting that `lock_1` is the set `{0, 2}`.
If we want to say that `lock_1` is the empty set or the set `{2}`, we should assert:

```
(assert (or (forall ((x Int)) (not (lock_1 x))) 
            (forall ((x Int)) (= (lock_1 x) (= x 2)))))
```

To say that `lock_1` may contain only the values 2 and 3, we should assert:

```
(assert (forall ((x Int)) (=> (lock_1 x) (or (= x 2) (= x 3)))))
```

Note that, I'm using implication (`=>`) instead of equality. In this case, we have that `lock_1` may be one of the following sets: `{}` (empty set), `{2}`, `{3}`, or `{2, 3}`.

The command `define-fun` does not take functions as arguments.
The command `define-fun` is just defining a macro. 
It does not add any extra power to Z3.

If you want a more powerful language to interact with Z3, you should consider Z3Py, the Python front-end for Z3. Here is an example using Z3Py (it is also available online [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/feB3)).

```py
# Declare a function from Int to Bool
lock_1 = Function('lock_1', IntSort(), BoolSort())
x = Int('x')

s = Solver()
# Assert that lock_1 is the empty set
s.add(ForAll(x, Not(lock_1(x))))
print(s.check())

# Declare a function that returns x*x if x is in s1 but not in s2
# Remark: example is a Python function that builds a Z3 expression.
def example(s1, s2, x):
    # Remark: the function If creates a Z3 if expression.
    return If(And(s1(x), Not(s2(x))), x*x, 0)

lock_2 = Function('lock_2', IntSort(), BoolSort())

s = Solver()
a = Int('a')
s.add(a == example(lock_1, lock_2, 3))
s.add(lock_1(3))
s.add(Not(lock_2(3)))
print(s)
print(s.check())
m = s.model()
print(m[a])
```

**END EDIT**

Comment: So how can I generate for the same set, the empty set or the set {2}? Or it is not possible to do? I edited the question.

Comment: In Z3Py how can I limit a set? For example: The set contains only 2 and 3, and may be empty.

Comment: Everything we write in the SMT-LIB format can be written in Z3Py. The only difference is the syntax. Here is a tutorial on Z3Py: http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/tutorial/guide

Comment: The assertion `(assert (forall ((x Int)) (=> (lock_1 x) (or (= x 2) (= x 3)))))` is "saying" that `lock_1` may be one of the following sets: `{}` (empty set), `{2}`, `{3}`, or `{2, 3}`.